# Photodiode amplification works with LM258N but doesn't with LF356N

Tags: operational-amplifier, saturation

The circuit is as follows

[image: Photodiode transimpedance amplifier]

I'm powering the op-amp from a 9V battery.

It gives me constant 3.6V at the output and it doesn't change with changing the illumination of the diode.

I tried replacing the 1M resistor with 10K and 10R, but it doesn't change anything.

I've double checked the pinout and it appears to be correct based on the datasheets that I can find.

The offset pins are floating in my circuit if this is of importance in this case.

When I swap LF356N with LM258N or CA3140 it works as expected with the output reacting to changes in the illumination.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

LF356 is not a single-supply op-amp - ie. the input common mode range (and output swing with a load to the negative rail) do not include the negative rail. The CA3140 and LM358 are single-supply op-amps.

The op-amp in your circuit can only be in balance when both inputs are at the negative rail, hence it cannot work with the LF356. As you can see from the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lf356.pdf) the op-amp needs the inputs to be at least 4 or 5V above the negative rail to be guaranteed to work properly. The output swing is a similar problem- it cannot approach the negative rail closer than a few volts, depending on the load.

[image]

If you add a negative supply (eg. -5V), just for the op-amp negative rail, it will work properly.

Comment: How many times does this crop up.......

Comment: @Andyaka At least weekly I think.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know how to read the datasheet properly.